# GPS Tracking - points too far

Tags: javascript, navigation, gps, geolocation, leaflet

I'm making an application where I'm tracking user's position and showing it on the map. Problem is, that sometimes I'm not getting the position for a while and then there is a long distance between the two points I got.

I'd like to do something like animating the user's position so that there are no such gaps. Problem is how to do it to minimize problems like predicting user's position too far from real position etc.

I know the route on which user wants to be navigated and I've already solved problem when user was not on exactly on the road by sticking the user on the route when near enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two options:

1. Some GPS tracking devices/apps can send reports by distance. You can use that feature.
2. Use some navigation API to create a route between two distant points. It should work in most, but no all cases.